# Modal ViewController turning black when it shows up seemingly randomly (iOS 11 beta 2 issue?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm writing my app using Xcode 9 beta 2 and I'm randomly getting a black screen whenever my modal pops up. I've tried various ways to fix it and I was wondering if any of you have suggestions. Right now I just use the basic `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toVC" sender:nil];` and I've got the segue and such setup properly. The biggest issue is that it's seemingly **random**! As in sometimes the view loads perfectly fine and sometimes it just loads black.

[The black image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9ysm.png)

I have absolutely zero idea why this is happening. I've tested on the iOS 10.0 simulator and the iOS 11.0 beta 2 simulator and it happens in both places. If any of you have any insight as to why this is happening then please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried view debugging?

Comment: FYI - beta 3 has been out for some time now. There's no reason to keep using out-of-date betas.